# Precision error that leads to different results

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I'm a beginner that uses Codeabbey and the likes to keep learning the wolfram language. So, one problem had me use real numbers with a lot of decimal digits for the first time and I'm having trouble grasping the whole precision-accuracy concept. In order to solve the problem I have to be able to handle such numbers and it's not working as I expected.
Pulled from the example data, I copy two reals over to the notebook as text

`"0.59912051 0.64030348"//StringCases[#, NumberString] & // ToExpression`
After applying the `ToExpression` function the numbers are truncated to 6 decimal digits but I have come to the conclusion that this is a readability feature because if I append `//InputForm` the missing digits are there and I guess the full form is used in further computations.

So, in baby steps, I append a `//Total` and get `1.2394239900000001` whereas adding the numbers by hand in gcalc I get `1.23942399` which is correct and just makes plain arithmetic sense. Now these numbers and more of them have to go through an equation involving multiplication, powers and exponents and of course the result is different than the provided control result based on the example data. But if a simple addition fails how can I expect to reach the same result? In other words where did that additional `00000001` come from?
Now, I know certain similar questions have been asked and certain answers have been given, I just don't get them...

Comment: see: [What is special about 70.329862](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63317/5478) and [115705](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115705/5478). And in general : [tags/arbitrary-precision/hot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/arbitrary-precision/hot)

Comment: @Kuba Thanks a bunch! Great learning resources and a way to solve my problem at hand

Comment: I'm glad it helps. Let me know if any of those topics answers your question directly. If no one feel free to self answer.

Comment: @Kuba [115705](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115705/5478) does. Should I have marked this somehow? Not that familiar with stackexchange yet either I'm afraid...

Comment: Done, thanks and good luck :)